# looking for some cool Silverlight chart Demos

Tags: sql, sql-server, silverlight, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am currently using Reporting Service of SQL Server 2008, and I think the user interface is not very elegant. And I want to use Silverlight as user interface to render reporting service backend data. Two questions,

1. Is it possible? Reporting Service exposes interface which Silverlight could retrieve data and render?
2. I am looking for some cool Demos, better free with source codes, which could dynamically show different kinds of charts, curves on coordinates based on the data retrieved by some data source (e.g. Reporting Service).

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: I understand you are looking for Silverlight however have you had at Microsoft Chart Controls Add-on for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. Samples are here  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart these look much better than the reporting services charts.

Comment: Cool John! It is for Reporting Service or general ASP.Net control?

Comment: ASP.net but I am sure somewhere someone has used it for reporting services.

Comment: Cool, John. Can you reply as answer please, I want to mark your reply as answered to benefit others.

Answer (score 5):

Some Silverlight components that might be worth considering with links to their demo page:

- [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) - free. [Demo page](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html): different charts (without source code)
- [Visiblox](http://visiblox.com) - free and premium, free version comes with watermark. [Examples page](http://www.visiblox.com/examples): showing different charts (most with source code) **Full disclosure**: I have been heavily involved in developing of this component.
- [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/) - free and commercial. [Examples page](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_charts_gallery.php): showing a wide range of charts (without source code)
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/chart.aspx) - commercial. [Examples page](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook): some noce examples (with source code)

Answer (score 4):

Well, not SSRS but rocks:

http://www.visifire.com/

Free to use, SL based chart library, pretty impressing (good demos, you can even create charts there on the fly).

[image]

Cheers
  Braulio

Comment: What is the pros and cons compared of using Silverlight chart control v.s. ASP.Net chart control?

Answer (score 1):

Dundas just add new [silverlight add-on](http://www.dundas.com/company/support/addons/Silverlight.aspx) features which lets you integrate Dundas Chart into your silverlight applications.
See silverlight add-on demo [here](http://demos6.dundas.com/Silverlight/)

FYI, [Dundas Data Visualization](http://www.dundas.com/Products/Chart/RS/index.aspx) is now [acquired by Microsoft](http://www.dundas.com/Company/Media/PressSQL2008.aspx) for its SQL Server Reporting Service 2008 charting controls. So, [Microsoft Chart control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) is based on Dundas Chart source code.

Comment: Very cool, a further question -- what is the pros and cons compared of using Silverlight chart control v.s. ASP.Net chart control?

Comment: Since I never use the silverlight add-on, I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

[Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight) from Microsoft contains chart controls (scottmarlowe hinted at this, but here is a direct link).

You could also have a look at [Silverlight Viewer for Reporting Services](http://perpetuumsoft.com/Silverlight-Viewer-for-Reporting-Services.aspx) from Perpetuum Software which may be what you are looking for or the exact opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm kinda partial to Telerik's control. I've been using their ASP, then AJAX controls for about 3 years now... though they aren't free. They Do have a nice Silverlight package, including a charting control.

http://www.telerik.com

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
have you tried on codeplex?
There are lot of opensource free controls.
Have fun. :)

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?ProjectSearchText=chart%20silverlight

[codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?ProjectSearchText=chart%20silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

Since several people have mentioned Telerik Charts, I thought you should take a look at Telerik's new [ChartView](http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/controls/chartview.aspx). Here is a [blog post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Telerik-XAML-Q3-11-Beta-A-Walkthrough-Part-3-RadChartingKit.aspx) detailing how you can use it. You can also review all of Telerik's charts by clicking [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook).